# Fetch NSSet from Core Data Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsset

I have a NSManagedObject class (SearchHistory.swift) which has a relationship with the (Hospital.swift) class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(SearchHistory)
public class SearchHistory: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var search_id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged public var hospitals: NSSet

}
```

I'm trying to fetch hospitals NSSet, but it gives me a compilation error:

> Use of undeclared type 'SearchHistory'

although I'm fetching other entities in the same way and there is no error.

```
let AppDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let Context: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel.managedObjectContext!
            let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SearchHistory")
            var search = Context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as! [SearchHistory] // ERROR HERE :(
            for (var x=0; x<search.count; x++) {
                let hospitalsArray: NSArray = search[x].hospitals.allObjects
                
                for hospital in hospitalsArray {
                    println(hospital.hospital_name)
                }
            }
```

Why I'm getting this error? Is it correct to get the NSSet with the code I wrote?

Comment: If that's the real error message, you have a spelling error somewhere on "SearchHistroty".

Comment: @PhillipMills it's a spelling mistake